# IndexedDB: How to implement conditions using Index(OR)

Tags: jquery, html, cursor, indexeddb

I am using IndexDB for my mobile application. 95% its working but I am stuck in one condition.
How do I implement "**OR CONDITION**" of SQL in INDEXDB
**eg: WHERE A="xyz" or B="abc" or C="pqr"**

I searched on google but could not find any solution.Can some one please guide me how to proceed! Below is my code, but it is for the below example.
**eg: WHERE A="xyz" and B="abc" and C="pqr"**

```
var range = IDBKeyRange.only(lowerBound);
    var index = objectStore.index(IndexName);
    index.openCursor(range).onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) 
          callback(cursor,db);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can can do the search, but you cannot use indexed search. Here is the sample code:

```
var transaction = indexedDB.open(dbName);
transaction.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var database = e.target.result;
    var transaction = database.transaction(storeName, 'readonly');
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    var cursorRequest = objectStore.openCursor();
    var items = [];
    cursorRequest.onsuccess = function (event)
    {
        if (event.target.result)
        {   
            if(event.target.result.value["A"] == "xyz" || event.target.result.value["B"] == "abc"  || event.target.result.value["C"] == "pqr")
                items.push(event.target.result.value);
            event.target.result['continue']();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED as feedback from @Rohit

A trivial solution will be query all three cursors and sorted merge in memory. However it is not scalable and could not utilise limit.

The solution is multi-query as explained in google io session [next gen query](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/next-gen-queries-appengine.html).

Basically open your three cursors and iterate next step by the lowest key value. Using my open source library, ydn-db, it will be as follow:

```
var q1 = ydn.db.IndexValueCursors.where('store', 'A', '=', 'abc'); 
var q2 = ydn.db.IndexValueCursors.where('store', 'B', '=', 'def'); 
var q3 = ydn.db.IndexValueCursors.where('store', 'C', '=', 'hij'); 

var result = [];
db.open(function(cursors) {
  var lowest_primary_key = ... find from cursors array
  if (lowest_primary_key) {
     result.push(cursors[lowest_cursor_idx].value);
     var cnt_next = [];
     cnt_next[lowest_cursor_idx] = true; // continue only lowest cursor
     return cnt_next;
  }
}, [q1, q2, q3], 'readonly');
```

Notice that we are utalizing that fact that all cursors are sorted by primary key. And hence result is sorted by primary key. If we were wanted to be sorted by other index, we need to use compound key instead.

Without the library, implementation will be quite messy by async boilerplate codes. But doable and implementation is very straight forward.

Comment: I believe what you have said is for WHERE A ='abc' or A='def' or more appropriate  WHERE A in ('abc','def','hij') but what I want is WHERE A="xyz" or B="abc" or C="pqr"

Comment: sorry, I slipped. Basically they are same, since we are concern only with primary key.